# Angular 2 npm install dependencies missing

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am developing my Angular 2 application local. Somewhen I put my app to the server (automatically) without the nodes_module folder. Then I do a npm install on my Angular 2 project and build it afterwards. I was wondering why my app wouldn´t work. It always said "Loading..." without any errors. I compared the node_modules folder of the working and non working versions and noticed that some dependencies were missing.
I think these are subdependencies because they are all in node_modules folders like:

```
..\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve
```

Anyone has a clue why these dependencies are not installed?

Answer (score 2):

in your local copy you have probably installed a packed but ommitted the --save flag when running `npm install some-package`. This mean that the package is installed in you local copies `node_modules` but not listed in your package.json. When you run `npm install` on the server it will not install that package as its not in your `package.json`.

To fix it on your local copy run `npm install enhanced-resolve --save` (or the package you think is missing) then upload your local `package.json` to the server and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Don´t think that this is the answer since these are subdependencies as stated above. They are already in the package.json file but in subfolders of other packages. I would have expected that npm install would resolve these. But obviously it does not.